# get actionBar inside fragment using androidx

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-actionbar, androidx

I just want to get actionBar in a fragment with a function and I am using Kotlin language and AndroidX.

this is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    fun getActiobar() : ActionBar
    {
        return  activity.actionBar
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is android.app.ActionBar! but androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar was expected.

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  `activity` property of `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` gives you the `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` "this fragment is currently associated with" (quoted from the documentation available in Android Studio)

The `actionBar` property of `FragmentActivity` on the other hand will give you an `android.app.ActionBar` which is not compatible with the legacy `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` or its AndroidX equivalent `androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar`

Since `FragmentActivity` does not have a `supportActionBar` property, you'll have to cast the `FragmentActivity` to `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class TestFragment: Fragment() {

    fun getActionbar() : ActionBar?
    {
        return (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
    }
}
```

Note: I added the "?" because `supportActionBar` may be `null`

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your XML view you are defining an actionBar that is not AndroidX.

The translated error means that in that function you are wanting to return an object `androidx.appcompat.action.ActionBar` but `activity.actionBar` is an `android.app.ActionBar!` . You must take that into account and modify it in the corresponding styles.

I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you import androidx
***import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;***

initial *private ActionBar actionBar;*

Then add this inside the protected void onCreate calss

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Your Tittle");
```

That's all.